# How do I estimate temporary storage needs for a Postgres query?

Tags: postgresql

Running queries on Amazon RDS Postgres instance.  I have a couple of tables that are just over 1TB in size, not including indexes.  I'm having trouble getting queries to run against these tables due to how RDS allocates temp storage. How do I estimate how much temporary storage is required to complete a query -- I'm interested both in determining how large an RDS machine I'll need, and also in how to minimize temporary storage needs for any given query.